Is it possible to use delegated access with a confidential client, in the Microsoft Authentication Library?
When I use a client secret authentication flow with a confidential client, how could I authenticate a user (one that connects as an HTTP client to my website, or any other method of network access) and use delegated access?
I understand how to do so with a public client. I could also use a public client flow on this server, but that would make little sense as my server should technically be a confidential client.
Minimal working example (if "MY.\{-}" is replaced with valid a valid set of client secret, client ID, and tenant ID):
package main

import (
        "context"
        "fmt"

        "github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/apps/confidential"
)

func main() {
        cred, err := confidential.NewCredFromSecret("MY_CLIENT_SECRET")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        confidential_client, err := confidential.New(
                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+"MY_TENANT_ID",
                "MY_CLIENT_ID",
                cred,
        )
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        result, err := confidential_client.AcquireTokenByCredential(
                context.Background(),
                []string{"User.Read"},
        )
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(result)
}

Results:
{
        "error": "invalid_scope",
        "error_description": "AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope User.
Read openid offline_access profile is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI). Trace ID: REDACTED Correlation ID: REDACTED Timestamp: 2024-08-16 03:46:42Z",
        "error_codes": [1002012],
        "timestamp": "2024-08-16 03:46:42Z",
        "trace_id": "REDACTED",
        "correlation_id":"REDACTED" 
}


The scope must be https://graph.microsoft.com/.default for AcquireTokenByCredential flow. Let me know if it works

For confidential client you cannot use delegated access

@Rukmini I'm confused because https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-acquire-cache-tokens seems to suggest that confidentail clients can: (1) acquire tokens for the application itself, (2) use the OBO flow (which doesn't make sense for me because I have no JS or any such frontend, and I don't intend to call APIs, I just need to authenticate users), and (3) Acquire tokens using the authorization code flow

@Rukmini I thought that simply authenticating users with MSAL, from a Web app, requires delegated access

what is the scope you want to pass?  and What is the API you want to call?

@Rukmini The only scope I need is User.Read, namely to read the user's display name, email, and some sort of unique user ID (a UUID that doesn't change would do)

Yes it will work but the scope for confidential client must be https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Confidential client only works with application type API permissions hence you need to grant User.Read.All application type API permission as User.Read is delegated

To be more clear, if the user interaction is involved and if you want to retrieve details of the signed in user then you cannot make use of  confidential client flow. You need to make use of authorization code flow with User.Read permission

Understood, I suppose I'll just use a public client flow (since it's impossible for me to get User.Read.All due to organization policies). That does leave me wondering how https://github.com/rayluo/identity works...

Sorry, does an authorization code flow always involve a public client? Conversely, is it possible to limit the use of my registration's authorization code flow to a client authenticated with a client secret?

No issues you can go with  public client flow

Can I post an answer?

Please do... thank you!

@NaveenSharma I'll do so if this is actually the solution that I end up with, as I'm experimenting with using OpenID connect. Though, I understand the concept of accepting answers now. Thank you!


Note that: Confidential client only works with Application type API permissions and with no user interaction involved.

For sample, I tried to generate token via postman and got the same error as you:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


The error "The provided value for scope User.Read is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI)" usually occurs if the scope while using Confidential client is not suffixed by /.default. To resolve the error use https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
Confidential client doesn't suit your scenario as you want to pass scope as User.Read  and do not want to pass client secret you can make use of public client flow.

If there is user interaction involved, and you want to retrieve details of the signed in user then you need to make use of any user interactive flow.

It involves granting delegated API permissions.


And then call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me endpoint to fetch the signed in user details.



I was originally unsure if using public client flow was appropriate because I only want my web application's backend to be able to use this web registration. Now that I think of it, setting a correct redirect URI should mitigate this.

Yes you need to set redirect URI
